# Upload a file to a Google Drive Folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have an existing File object, created during my program. How can I use the drive API to upload this to a specific folder?

I understand it's something like this:

```
String folderId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E";
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
.setFields("id, parents")
.execute();
 System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

But

- How do I create the driveService object
- How do I replicate the above
  if I want to use a File object generated in my program, not one that
  exists on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

For Creating driveService(`com.google.api.services.drive.Drive`) class you need Google Single SignOn, And also you need to add the scope in [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com), and you need to use `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder#Builder` for creating the class.

For Auth process, you can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)

For Complete Sample for Android, you can refer to [this class](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/deprecation/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/driveapimigration/MainActivity.java)